# What door is recommended when I want to noise dampen my furnace room?

Tags: doors, basement, furnace, ventilation, noise-reduction

Our basement is being renovated. Aside from the furnace room, it will have a mother-in-law suite, a common area, a bathroom, and another bedroom. Our bedrooms, which are next to the furnace room, are getting noise dampened.

We were thinking of a louvered door, but it might defeat the purpose of having the basement noise reduced. If we used a solid core door, we might encounter issues with ventilation, but we're not entirely sure if our furnace room needs ventilation.

Our tankless water heater will be placed outside, but of course, we have the sump pump so I think that needs ventilation.

Comment: You've already said it: If you don't need the ventilation -- if there's enough airflow through the space without it -- the louvered door is not the right choice. So your first step is to determine whether you actually need that or not. Probably not.

Comment: Best is to have the chimney draw and CO checked with "door" closed (you could put a drop cloth across the area of the intended door).

Answer (score 1):

How old is the house? Most utility rooms should have a fresh air inlet. It usually looks like a round insulated duct that opens to the room. More modern houses have an air exchanger to bring in fresh air. Also you may want to do a radon test, seeing people will be sleeping there. If it's high they will usually vent your sump pump pit outside. If you have a contractor he should be able to answer these questions. If there is no fresh air vent I would install one. Going with the solid core door is the way to go.